# Reflecting FSC Data Model Changes in Data Cloud

Tags: financial-services-cloud, datacloud, salesforce-cdp, data-streams

I'm working on a Data Cloud (CDP) implementation. I'm ingesting data from Financial Services Cloud using Data Bundles. The CRM team is making multiple object relationship changes in FSC.

My understanding is that data bundles take a snapshot of the data in FSC. How do I most efficiently reflect all changes made in FSC in my Data Cloud streams and mapping?